# docker exec command doesn't return after completing execution

Tags: docker, exec

I started a docker container based on an image which has a file "run.sh" in it. Within a shell script, i use docker exec as shown below

```
docker exec <container-id> sh /test.sh
```

test.sh completes execution but docker exec does not return until i press ctrl+C. As a result, my shell script never ends. Any pointers to what might be causing this.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Same problem here. Any solution yet?

Comment: Didn't find any solution.

Comment: Which version of docker? Did you exec before on the same container with a different script/command?

Comment: Same issue without any explanation nor way to debug this. Could someone help me out ?

Answer (score 4):

I could get it working with adding the `-it` parameters:

`docker exec -it <container-id> sh /test.sh`

Comment: This worked for me as well, despite it not really making sense. [The documentation][1] says:
> --interactive , -i   Keep STDIN open even if not attached
> --tty , -t   Allocate a pseudo-TTY

[1]: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/#options

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33039#issuecomment-353250651), this "hanging" behavior occurs when you have processes that keep stdout or stderr open.

To prevent this from happening, each long-running process should:

1. be executed in the **background**, and
2. close *both* stdout and stderr or **redirect** them to files or `/dev/null`.

I would therefore make sure that any processes already running in the container, as well as the script passed to `docker exec`, conform to the above.

Answer (score 0):

Mine works like a charm with this command. Maybe you only forgot the path to the binary (**/bin/sh**)?

```
docker exec 7bd877d15c9b /bin/bash /test.sh
```

**File location at**

```
/test.sh
```

**File Content:**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hi"
echo
echo "This works fine"
sleep 5
echo "5"
```

**Output:**

```
ArgonQQ@Terminal ~  docker exec 7bd877d15c9b /bin/bash /test.sh
Hi

This works fine
5
ArgonQQ@Terminal ~
```

Comment: Yes, it works for most of the cases. To rule out something wrong with my test.sh, I added an echo statement at the end of my test.sh file and that gets printed as well. docker exec doesn't return for some reason.

Comment: This answer is neither answering the question "what can be causing this", nor does it offer a solution.

Answer (score 0):

My case is a script a.sh with content
like

```
php test.php &
```

if I execute it like

```
docker exec contianer1 a.sh
```

It also never returned.

After half a day googling and trying
changed a.sh to

```
php test.php >/tmp/test.log 2>&1 &
```

It works!

So it seems related with stdin/out/err.

```
>/tmp/test.log 2>&1
```

Please try.

And please note that my test.php is a dead loop script that monitors a specified process, if the process is down, it will restart it. So test.php will never exit.

Answer (score -1):

OK, I got it.

docker stop a590382c2943

docker start a590382c2943

then will be ok.

```
docker exec -ti a590382c2943 echo "5"
```

will return immediately, while add -it or not, no use

actually, in my program, the deamon has the std input and std output, std err. so I change my python deamon like following, things work like a charm:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # do the UNIX double-fork magic, see Stevens' "Advanced
    # Programming in the UNIX Environment" for details (ISBN 0201563177)

    try:
        pid = os.fork()
        if pid > 0:
            # exit first parent
            os._exit(0)
    except OSError, e:
        print "fork #1 failed: %d (%s)" % (e.errno, e.strerror)
        os._exit(0)
    # decouple from parent environment
    #os.chdir("/")
    os.setsid()
    os.umask(0)
    #std in out err, redirect
    si = file('/dev/null', 'r')
    so = file('/dev/null', 'a+')
    se = file('/dev/null', 'a+', 0)
    os.dup2(si.fileno(), sys.stdin.fileno())
    os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
    os.dup2(se.fileno(), sys.stderr.fileno())
    # do second fork
    while(True):
        try:
            pid = os.fork()
            if pid == 0:
                serve()
            if pid > 0:
                print "Server PID %d, Daemon PID: %d" % (pid, os.getpid())
                os.wait()
                time.sleep(3)
        except OSError, e:
            #print "fork #2 failed: %d (%s)" % (e.errno, e.strerror)
            os._exit(0)
```